# C# replace string in string

Tags: c#, string, replace

Is it possible to replace a substring in a string without assigning a return value?

I have a string:

```
string test = "Hello [REPLACE] world";
```

And I want to replace the substring `[REPLACE]` with something else:

```
test = test.replace("[REPLACE]", "test");
```

This works fine, but how can I do it without assigning the return value to a variable?

I want something like this:

```
test.replace("[REPLACE]", "test");
```

Answer (score 43):

As mentioned by dlev, you can't do this with `string` as strings are *immutable* in .NET - once a string has been constructed, there's nothing you can do (excluding unsafe code or reflection) to change the contents. This makes strings generally *easier* to work with, as you don't need to worry about defensive copying, they're naturally thread-safe etc.

Its mutable cousin, however, is [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy.aspx) - which has a [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.replace.aspx) method to perform an in-object replacement. For example:

```
string x = "Hello [first] [second] world";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(x);
builder.Replace("[first]", "1st");
builder.Replace("[second]", "2nd");

string y = builder.ToString(); // Value of y is "Hello 1st 2nd world"
```

Answer (score 29):

You can't, because **`string` is immutable**. It was designed so that any "changes" to a string would actually result in the creation of a new `string` object. As such, if you don't assign the return value (which is the "updated" string, actually copy of the original string with applied changes), you have effectively discarded the changes you wanted to make.

If you wanted to make in-place changes, you could in theory work directly with a `char[]` (array of characters), but that is **dangerous, and should be avoided.**

Another option (as pointed out by Mr. Skeet below) is to use `StringBuilder` and its `Replace()` method. That being said, simple replacements like the one you've shown are quite fast, so you may not want to bother with a `StringBuilder` unless you'll be doing so quite often.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You have to assign the value, as strings are immutable.

*[Built-in reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types)*

Answer (score 2):

Strings in .NET are immutable. They cannot be edited in-line.

The closest you can get to in-line editing is to create a `StringBuilder` from a string. In-line fiddles with its contents and then get it to spit a string back out again.

But this will still produce a new string rather than altering the original. It is a useful technique, though, to avoid generating lots of intermediary strings when doing lots of string fiddling, e.g. in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Strings are immutable in .NET.

Comment: you are correct, but please add some extra information for people who doesn't know what is inmutable, like code or any link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as in C# strings are immutable. Something like this would violate that.

You need to have the return type of *string*, because the one you're working with cannot change.

Comment: You should probably include some information about immutable for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to fetch a string from HTML content and pass it to StringBuilder and set the value from your variable. You cannot do string.replace. You have to use StringBuilder while manipulating. Here in the HTML page I added [Name] which is replaced by Name from code behind. Make sure [Name] is unique or you can give any unique name.

```
string Name = txtname.Text;
string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/invoice.html"));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(contents);

builder.Replace("[Name]", Name);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(builder.ToString());
```